# Listings settings for command line arguments

Tags: listings, verbatim, code

I am typesetting a set of instructions which includes several (Unix) command line arguments.  I have been using the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package to include these arguments, but the colouring is less than ideal.  Weird words like "test" are bolded.  Is there something more like [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), which can highlight flags and filenames and the like?

As an example something like

```
program-name -some-option-flag -some-other-option-flag -i /location/of/input/file -o /location/of/output/file
```

Comment: Would you please provide an example of what you're doing?

Comment: @Dave: You can use the package `minted` which uses pygments.

Comment: It is possible to specify the language used in a listing, and even define your own language or formatting. As suggested, provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to allow others to work with something.

Comment: Thanks for providing the command line that you are tying to typeset, but it would be even more helpful to have a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That way we can see exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Without a full MWE it not clear exactly what issue you are having. But, you can define you own keywords that you want highlighted. Below I have defined `cd`, `man`, `ls`,and `uptime` to be emphasized in blue, and the keyword `filename` to be emphasized in red. So when these appear in the listing the specified formatting is applied.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{%
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},%
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,%
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,%
    }%

\lstset{emph={%  
    cd, man, ls,uptime%
    },emphstyle={\color{blue}\bfseries\underbar},%
    morekeywords={filename},
    keywordstyle={\color{red}\ttfamily}
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
man cd
ls -lF test/
rm filename
uptime
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```